# Dropdown selection display results from different <div>

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
  <label for="country">Country : </label>
  <select id="country">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option name="CountryRevenue">Revenue</option>
    <option name="CountryQuantity">Quantity</option>
    <option name="CountryGrossMargin">Gross Margin</option>
  </select>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("#country") = $(this).val();
    $("#results");
  </script>
</body>
```

How do I insert a different `<div>` as shown below as results? If revenue is chosen, first `<div>` will be run.

- if revenue chosen ->

  ```
  <div id="Revenue" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
  ```
- if quantity chosen ->

  ```
  <div id="Revenue" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
  ```

Comment: arent your revenue and quantity examples the same?? are they supposed to be? also - don't forget the $(document).ready(function{}) wrapper around your jquery/

Comment: You need to add a click/change handler to the select element and append/remove or show/hide the relevant div(s) from there. @gavgrif - OP doesn't need a document ready handler because their script is after the elements it refers to (assuming what they've shown above reflects their real html structure)..

Comment: @nnnnnn- maybe - but that jquery has multiple errors in  such a short section of code - perhaps it should be rewritten more betterer before the outcome can come out. Just Sayin'

Comment: *if quantity chosen ->  <div id="Quantity" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">

Comment: if all that is changing between the two divs, do't have two divs - use jQuery to dynamically change the ID attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are new to JS & HTML development. There are several errors in your code. The jquery in particular is not well formed. The select options should have `value` and not `name`;

You may want to pick up a book about jQuery or read the documentation online https://learn.jquery.com/ or [do a tutorial](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery).
Before that you will want to also get some basic understanding of javascript at [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript)

I wish you the best on your journey!

```js
$(function(){
  $('#country').on('change', function(){
      //hide all div inside the #results div
      $('#results div').hide();
      //show only the selected div (matched by select#country value)
      $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <label for="country">Country :</label>
  <select id="country">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option value="Revenue">Revenue</option>
    <option value="Quantity">Quantity</option>
    <option value="GrossMargin">Gross Margin</option>
  </select>
  <div id="results">
    <!-- I prefer the html all in here, but hidden than inserting with js. Note the display: none; css style. -->
    <div id="Revenue" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; display: none">Revenue</div>
    <div id="Quantity" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; display: none">Quantity</div>
    <div id="GrossMargin" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; display: none">Gross Margin</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Great post - very informative for new learners - would suggest one alteration - stripping the css out of the html and into css at the top (or external) and a discussion of the benefits of separating the structure and style of the code.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your expected result, use below option

1. Change function to get selected value
2. Check value using if condition
3. Append required div based on the selected value using append() method

HTML:

```
<body>
    <label for="country">Country : </label>
    <select id="country">
        <option>Please select</option>
        <option name="CountryRevenue">Revenue</option>
        <option name="CountryQuantity">Quantity</option>
        <option name="CountryGrossMargin">Gross Margin</option>
    </select>
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#Revenue{
    background: red;
}

#Quantity{
    background: green;
}

#Gross{
    background: yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#country").change(function() {
    var x = $("#country option:selected").text()
    if (x == 'Revenue') {
        $('#results').append('<div id="Revenue" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">');
    }

    if (x == 'Quantity') {
        $('#results').append('<div id="Quantity" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">');
    }

    if (x == 'Gross Margin') {
        $('#results').append('<div id="Gross" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">');
    }
})
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qNpzzx

Answer (score 0):

You need to add values to the select options and then use the val() in your jquery code.

```
     <body>
    <label for="country">Country : </label>
    <select id="country">
      <option>Please select</option>
      <option value="Revenue" name="CountryRevenue">Revenue</option>
      <option value="Quantity" name="CountryQuantity">Quantity</option>
      <option value="GrossMargin" name="CountryGrossMargin">Gross Margin</option>
    </select>
    <div id="results"></div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#country").on("change", function() {
 var val = $(this).val();
        $("#results").html("<div id='" + val + "' style='min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto' ></div>");
      })
    </script>
```